# Are temporary profiles copied from the "Default" profile?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-profile, profile

I am in a situation where I know users will be logging in with temporary profiles while we decommission a server.

I would like to make a small change that gets applied to newly created temporary profiles, mainly just adding a file to the app data folder.

When a temporary profile is created, is it just a copy of the "Default" profile folder? If so, can I simply add the file I need to the default profile folder, and have new temporary profiles get a copy of that file?

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: Are you asking because you think I should have tried before asking the question? I haven't tried it yet, as I was worried that futzing with the default system profile might have some negative repercussions. Just wanted to confirm the process Windows goes through when creating temporary profiles, and if this is a safe thing to do first.

Comment: Do it in the lab.  And yes, I am implying that you should test and then come back to us if you still have a question.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have a lab environment. I could setup a quick test on a Hyper-V VM on my PC, but not sure how people feel about unlicensed VMs like that?

Comment: For quick checks you can use the trial versions. Permanent lab setups need to be licensed normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a temporary profile is created, is it just a copy of the
>   "Default" profile folder? If so, can I simply add the file I need to
>   the default profile folder, and have new temporary profiles get a copy
>   of that file?

Yes.  Tested and verified on Win 7 SP1.

For future work I'd strongly encourage setting up a test environment.  even if you're short on budget you should be able to set up usable test environments using free hypervisors and Windows evaluation period.

Comment: Ok many thanks. Have deployed my file to the Default profile, so tomorrow should yield the results I was hoping for. Appreciate the advice on test setups. Wasn't sure if the evaluation period could be used for this purpose, especially if I have to reinstall repeatedly after the period expires.